# excluding a maven dependency from grails BuildConfig

Tags: java, maven, grails

I'm using grails 2.5 and was using grails spring websockets in my project and everything was ok. Now, as I want to implement login with Google added the maven dependency to BuildConfig for google api client:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
```

And now, when I run the app I get this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()
```

This is because there's a conflict between the Jackson libraries that spring websocket plugin and google api client are using.
As I could see, it looks like google api is using an outdated version of jackson.
Is it possible to exlude jackson to be imported from a maven dependency? I know that from a grails plugin is possible adding 'exclude'. But it doesn't seem to work for a maven dependency, I've added this but with no luck:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0', { excludes "com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.20.0" }
```

Just to remind, the google api client dependency is under 'dependencies' group in BuildConfig, which is using mavenCentral() to get the dependencies, not under 'plugins'.

Does anybody know how could I fix this?

thanks

EDIT: Probably not ideal, but I could solve this problem just adding the latest jackson dependency

```
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0', {
        excludes "com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.20.0"
    }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
```

Comment: try `excludes 'google-api-client-jackson2'` instead of full name. it works for us for simple dependencies without issues. Dependency must be defined under `dependencies{}` not `plugins{}`

Comment: @nelson687 have you ever figured out the answer to this?

Comment: I just went with the solution of adding the latest jackson dependency as stated in the EDIT part of the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.  Exclusions can work for plugins because the source is downloaded and compiled locally. For dependencies, you are using maven, which is downloading jars. You can't tell maven to exclude part of the jar.

The Google code you want to use may depend on other methods of the Jackson version it depends on that are not present in the version you want to use.  In that case, if Maven allowed excluding Google's declared version of Jackson, the Google library would not even work.  (The same problem would occur for plug-ins if they needed a different version of some library at compile time.)

You could try making your own version of the Google jar that uses your preferred version of Jackson. If it doesn't depend on methods from the older version of Jackson, that could work.